# How to \label something whose text wraps?

Tags: cross-referencing

What construct should I use to lay something out so that it has a `\label` (as it will be the target of future cross-references), and where the text within it wraps?

Environments `align` and `gather` enable the cross-referencing using `\label` and `\ref` but not the line-wrapping. (Text should wrap automatically, so that, when I edit the text in future, that doesn't entail me finding out which words should begin the respective lines.)

I thought the following would do, but no label appears in the output PDF, and the `\ref` reference is typeset as the section number (if the text is in a section).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The first few values are as follows:

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{p{15cm}}
$m = 2$, 3, 5, 11, 29, 47, 59, 71, 83, 101, 131, 137, 149, 167, 173, 197, 233, 251, 257, 269, 281, 293, 311, 317, 347, 443, 461, 467, 479, 491, 503, 569,\dots.
\end{tabular}\label{m}
\end{table}

Lorem ipsum etc.

Later text referring back to sequence \ref{m}.
\end{document}
```

I tried the same but with `$\begin{array}` and `\end{array}$` instead of `tabular`, but that didn't produce a label either.

Although I have used the environment `table` to try to get what I want, the thing is semantically some text such as would be laid out using a `gather` environment (just with line-wrapping). So I'd like it to look like a numbered equation. So giving the `table` a `\caption` would not produce what I would like.

Furthermore, as befits ia numbered equation, the layout engine should allocate the same number for the label as it would if the `\label` had occurred in a `gather` or `align` environment. What environment, though, allows this and also allows automatic text line wrapping?

Comment: what output to you want from \ref{m}? What should it reference?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A number -- exactly which number is out of my control. I would like the same format of cross-references as you would get from `\begin{align} a &= b \label{ab}\end{align}`. So that if the layout engine typesets `(5)` for the label, then it should typeset `5` for a later `\ref{ab}`..

Comment: sorry but if you simply want an arbitrary number, then type `42` instead of \ref{m}. If you want a specific number, you should say which one of all numbers in your example you want, and why this specific one and not the next.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I see your point... I would like the number to be the same as the equation number which the layout engine would allocate if the `\label` were in an `align` or `gather` environment. So the question is which environments are there, which are like `align` or `gather` in that a `\label` in it turns into a number in the same equation-numbering sequence, and which enables automatic line-wrapping. I'll update the question.

Comment: I'm afraid your write-up is very confusing. For instance, why do you show `table` and `tabular` environments if what you really want to cross-reference is a multi-line equation? Or am I missing something rather fundamental? Please clarify.

Comment: You can add to every environment a numbering system, Simply do `\newcounter{rosiecounter}` in preamble,  and in the environment `\refstepcounter{rosiecounter}\therosiecounter \label{m}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only label a caption, if you're in a `table` environment.

But I guess you want something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The first few values are as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{m}
\parbox[b]{0.8\displaywidth}{\raggedright
  $m ={}$2, 3, 5, 11, 29, 47, 59, 71, 83, 101, 131, 137, 149, 167, 173,
  197, 233, 251, 257, 269, 281, 293, 311, 317, 347, 443, 461, 467, 479,
  491, 503, 569, \dots.
}
\end{equation}
Lorem ipsum etc.

Later text referring back to sequence \ref{m}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good advice about `\parbox` (which I hadn't used before, and will now bear in mind) and `\displaywidth`.